# ¿Cómo puedo mandar al usuario a la app de correo electrónico que tenga instalada?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo un proyecto en el que me gustaría que al pulsar un botón, al usuario se le abra el selector de aplicaciones y pueda compartir un enlace. Lo que necesito es que pueda seleccionar solamente las apps de correo electrónico que tenga instaladas en su teléfono y el usuario decida cuál quiere usar. ¿Podríais ayudarme con alguna idea? Solamente tengo este código que abre la app que tú le pases, pero no detecta las que tiene instaladas.

```
try{
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.type = "text/plain"
            // Establecemos el enlace que se compartirá
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://www.google.es")
            // Nombre del paquete de la aplicación
            intent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana")
            startActivity(intent)
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Aplicación no instalada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas usando como nombre de paquete el de Facebook , esto es incorrecto:

```
 intent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana")
```

**Abrir aplicación para enviar correo electrónico.**

Para abrir algún cliente de correo electrónico en tu dispositivo usa:

```
    String address[] = new String[]{"PacoPepe@gmail.com"};
    String subject = "Te envió este email...";
    String message = "Con respecto a la pregunta ¿Cómo puedo mandar al usuario a la app de correo electrónico que tenga instalada?";

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, address);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message );
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

de esta forma se buscara en tu dispositivo que aplicación puede abrir para enviar el correo electrónico, si tienes varias se mostraría de esta forma:.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al seleccionar la aplicación para envió de correo electrónico podrás ver el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Sí, lo de facebook era un ejemplo para poner algo de código. Gracias por ayudarme, me ha servido.